# Why is the equal sign not working in SQL, where as same dates are being extracted with greater than and less than

Tags: sql, mysql, equality

I want to extract customers created on 2021-10-14 (yyyy-mm-dd),

```
select * from customers where created_at = '2021-10-14'
```

This is giving 0 rows as output.
Whereas this code is showing the data created on 2021-10-14:

```
select * from customers where created_at > '2021-10-14' and created_at < '2021-10-15'
```

why is equal to not working in the above query and why is greater than including the given date.

Comment: In your working example it is actually `created_at >= '2021-10-14'` and not just `=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because your `created_at` column is of type `datetime`. And for instance a created time of

```
'2021-10-14 12:00:00'
```

is not not the same as

```
'2021-10-14'
```

because it is actually comparing the time value too which is

```
'2021-10-14 00:00:00'
```

The query you used (with the fixed typo of `>=`) is actually the correct way to go since it is able to use indexes for better performance

```
select * 
from customers 
where created_at >= '2021-10-14' 
  and created_at < '2021-10-15'
```